# Vuejs, Get content of a $event.emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-events

I'm trying to get the content of a $event.emit, as below. In the first console.log, inside the function comes the content. Leaving the function, not the console.log of the variable.

```
mounted () {
  this.$events.on('emitEvent', function (eventData) {
    this.line = _.cloneDeep(eventData)
    console.log('1', this.line)
  })
  console.log('2', this.line)
}
```

I am using [this package](https://github.com/cklmercer/vue-events) for event handling.

Comment: what is this `console.log('1, this.line)`?

Comment: in the first console.log, shows the contents of the object. In the second console.log, out of function, returns nothing to me

Comment: you have put one single quote. is it intentional?

Comment: Here context of `this` is different than vue component. So to access your data property you can use closure  instead of function

Comment: Are you using [this package](https://github.com/cklmercer/vue-events)? As far as I know, there is no `$events` object in a default Vue instance...

Comment: yes exactly this package

Comment: If the solutions below don't work, I suspect that the problem is not in the event listener, but in the code that fires the event. Can you show us where you're firing the event `emitEvent`?

Comment: getLine (data) {
        this.$events.emit('emitEvent', data)
      },

Comment: maybe im missing something but why would the second console.log print anything? you just setup the event listener the event didnt trigger yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
mounted() {
   var $that = this;

   this.$events.on('emitEvent', function (eventData) {
        $that.line = _.cloneDeep(eventData);
        console.log('1', $that.line);
   })

   console.log('2', this.line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
this.$events.on('emitEvent', (eventData) => {
    this.line = _.cloneDeep(eventData)
    console.log('1', this.line)
  })
  console.log('2', this.line)
 }
```